# VS2012 - Source Control Explorer open at a specfic project/node

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, source-control-explorer

Is there a way to get the SourceControl Explorer start at a specific node by default when it is ope for the first time within VS.NET? I use VS2012 and connect to TFS2010. Got a big project tree and I find it time consuming to navigate the tree every time to get to my folder I work with quite often. I would like the tree to be open with a node (could be project/folder) of my choice selected by default when I open the explorer.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this brings you a step ahead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907614/automatically-open-source-control-explorer-when-visual-studio-starts-up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VS under Tools > Options > Source Control > Visual Studio Team Foundation Server. you can tick the checkbox 'Open SOurce Control Explorer to the most Recent Folder'.

This will do what you want, unless of course you close VS after looking at a different location in the source tree to normal.

[image: Open Last Source Control Folder]

Comment: and is still there in 2015

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by the Project's location setting:

In VS under Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General
Check that the projects location is set to the location where you store your projects.